# Can ATC separate IFR traffic in class A airspace from VFR traffic in class E?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airspace

Is it possible for ATC to apply 3 miles separation between an IFR aircraft in class A and a VFR aircraft operating in class E, just below class A?

Comment: You mean between Class B and E?  A is only above 18000ft.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Regulations and procedures are different in different countries, so for questions like this please always tell us which country you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnK Right, Class A starts at FL180, but just below that is Class E (except at Mt McKinley where it’s Class G right below it). Even KDEN Class B stops at 12000, leaving ~6000ft of Class E

Comment: Why would it be any different than any other situation? If they can’t do 3mi. horizontal than they would have to do 1000ft vertical.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that ATC only separates IFR traffic from **other** IFR traffic. So they would not provide separation from any VFR traffic no matter what the airspace (with the exception of Class B).

**AIM 4−4−11. IFR Separation Standards**

> b. Separation will be provided between all aircraft operating on IFR
>   flight plans except during that part of the flight (outside Class B
>   airspace or a TRSA) being conducted on a VFR−on−top/VFR conditions
>   clearance. Under these conditions, ATC may issue traffic advisories,
>   but it is the sole responsibility of the pilot to be vigilant so as to
>   see and avoid other aircraft.

Comment: Separation is also provided between IFR and SVFR traffic, but that's a very special (hah!) case.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible for U.S. ATC to apply 3 miles lateral separation between aircraft in Class A airspace (for example at FL180 or higher depending on local altimeter setting) and a VFR aircraft operating in class E airspace at any altitude below FL180 (by FAR no higher than 17,500 ft. msl).

But, ATC in the U.S. does not apply/provide required vertical or lateral separation between aircraft in Class A airspace (all of them operating under IFR) and VFR aircraft operating in Class E airspace.